# jQuery UI Sortable issue when dragged from bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[image]It works fine from top of page.
But once page scrolled, and the section when dragged in sortable list, the section doesn't appear to be at the position of cursor.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#accordionOne').sortable({
  start: function (e, ui) { 
   // modify ui.placeholder however you like
   // ui.placeholder.html("I'm modifying the placeholder element!");
   placeholderHeight = ui.item.outerHeight();
   ui.placeholder.height(placeholderHeight + 15);
   $('<div class="slide-placeholder-animator" data-height="' + placeholderHeight + '"></div>').insertAfter(ui.placeholder);
 },
 placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
 update: function(event, ui) {
  var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
  console.log("data",newOrder);
  var posting = $.post('/support_sections/update_order', {order:newOrder, position:'left'});

  // Put the results in a div
  posting.done(function( data ) {
    console.log("data",data);
  });
 }
});});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **overflow: hidden** from body.
Good Luck....

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful.